# Vb.net - Handling null or no values returned from SQL Command object

Tags: vb.net

we got this sql query:

```
Select EmployeeDesignation from Employee where EmployeeName = Paramater1
```

(Parameter1 is value is passed to this)

We are using this statement:
lEmployeeDesignation = _SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()

3 scenario's:

1. Returns the employee Designation (record exists in table)
2. No value is set in database for Parameter1 - so should return NULL (record exists but has no value)
3. No employee record exists so returns nothing (record doesn't exists)

I'm struggling with 2 and 3 scenario - incase of Scenario 3 we want the application to fail, but struggling how to trap this error.
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lEmployeeDesignation = _SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()
if lEmployeeDesignation IsNot Nothing AndAlso lEmployeeDesignation <> DBNull.Value then
    ' you have found your data....' 
Else
    if lEmployeeDesignation = DBNull.Value then
       ' you have a record for parameter1 but EmployeeDesignation field is null'
    End If
End If
```

Notice the use of AndAlso to shortcircuit the evaluation process. If the first condition is false then the second one is not evaluated

Comment: In the case where lEmployeeDesignation Is Nothing, then wouldn't this throw an exception when evaluating "if lEmployeeDesignation = DBNull.Value"?  Wouldn't you also want to preface that evaluation with "if lEmployeeDesignation IsNot Nothing AndAlso..."?

Comment: I like when someone, 4 years after the answer, downvote it and doesn't leave any comment to explain what he/she has fount to be wrong. I was very new to the site at that time but still today I can't see where this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the Null entirely by...

```
Select IsNull(Max(EmployeeDesignation),0) from Employee where EmployeeName = Paramater1
```

It's not a terribly good thing to do, but it works and as long as you're not doing too many of them it'll be fine.

You could also put in a Count(EmployeeDesignation)=0 to check scenario 3 though of course this couldn't be done on the same query or you would have to use a reader